# ionic2 + angular2 navigate to global pages on click

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

Ionic 2 comes with side menu and it is define on globally. (I have removed side menu)

I have created settings page and added cog button on the nav button, but how can I set link on it, so it can redirect.

I can do it from within that page, but I want to know how I can set global function or link, which just navigate to that page.

```
     <ion-navbar *navbar>

        <ion-title>My First List</ion-title>

        <ion-buttons end>
            <button light (click)="openPage('test')">
                <ion-icon name="cog"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>

    </ion-navbar>
```

openPage function is app.ts function, which is giving error.

> TypeError: l_context.openPage is not a function

I'm not sure how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the openPage method in the controller of your page.
The openPage function of the app.ts file can be used in the app.html file.

Comment: Is there way around to that?

Comment: I think the best way is to create a BaseController class with the required method, and to inherit from BaseController in each of your page controller.